# Way to vertically extend windows on one half of split screen onto other half

Tags: display, workspace, extended-desktop

I have a wide TV as a monitor and am looking for a way to divide the screen then extend the windows of applications on one half of the screen onto the second half of the screen.  In other words, turn my one landscape display into two portrait displays, and extend out of the bottom of one into the top of the other, like this:

[firefox extended vertically onto two halves of a split screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnPyh.png)

This will allow me to view more of the content of tall web pages at once, without having to scroll up and down so much.Two taskbars is not strictly necessary.

I have tried various demos such as Displayfusion, Actual Multiple MOnitors, and Maxto, but I haven't found any way of doing this.

Another possible solution is create a ghost monitor and extend the bottom of the real monitor display onto it, then bring the outputs of both monitors into a split screen on the real monitor (kind of merging them into my real display) but I haven't found any software which can do the part of bringing both outputs into the one display yet.

Windows 8.1
GeForce GTX260

Thanks.

Comment: ActualTools Window Manager (the entire suite) has various programs where one is to mirror part of a program into a different window. It does require that the window is visible, which in essence would require a second monitor that you don't need to view, but has to be turned on. The window would stretch from the first monitor to the second, and then a mirror of the second monitor would be cast to a window on the first monitor. Other than that, I don't think its possible. Maybe turn the screen 90 degrees and have it in portrait mode?

Comment: Ok I just tried your recommendation of ActualTools WM, and it gets the windows side by side and extended as I need, but unfortunately Firefox naturally continues to apply landscape orientation formatting to both windows leaving much of the right-hand sides of the webpages missing from each.  If I could some get Firefox to assume portrait orientation for both windows it would work perfectly.

Comment: You can try it with a different browser, or maybe making the actual window smaller. Also, ActualTools can move/resize a window on a rule base.